# Navigation submenu is coming down with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this navigation, everything works well. However, while I was testing I realised that if you hover on the first nav and scroll down, you will see that the submenu is coming with the mouse as well. How can I avoid it?

Note: Run it in full (desktop) screen size.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  }
}

$(".dropbtn").bind("click", function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1150) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.border-bottom {
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
  bottom: -11px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.logo img {
  width: 290px;
}

.custom-navi {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 55px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.dropbtn i {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #009fda;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 14px 22px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1300px) and (max-width:1600px) {
  .custom-navi {
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.7%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1150px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #002776;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .logo img {
    padding-left: 11px;
  }
  .custom-navi {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
  }
}

.active {
  color: #002776 !important;
}

#nav-icon3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009fda;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.main {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section class="custom-navi">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#">LOGO</a>

  </div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Statements of work     <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <!-- Subnavi Elements-->

        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">IT 
    </button>
      <!-- Subnavi Elements-->

    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <div id="nav-icon3">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</section>

<br><br><br><br>
<div class="main">
  Page Body
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  }
}

$(".dropbtn").bind("click", function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1150) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.border-bottom {
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
  bottom: -11px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.logo img {
  width: 290px;
}

.custom-navi {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 55px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.dropbtn i {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #009fda;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 14px 22px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1300px) and (max-width:1600px) {
  .custom-navi {
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.7%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1150px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .topnav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #002776;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .logo img {
    padding-left: 11px;
  }
  .custom-navi {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
  }
}

.active {
  color: #002776 !important;
}

#nav-icon3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009fda;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.main {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section class="custom-navi">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#">LOGO</a>

  </div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Statements of work     <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <!-- Subnavi Elements-->

        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
        <a>Contact persons</a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">IT 
    </button>
      <!-- Subnavi Elements-->

    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <div id="nav-icon3">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</section>

<br><br><br><br>
<div class="main">
  Page Body
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use position fixed if you dont want the element to stick to screen. use relative.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1150px)
.dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
  }
}

$(".dropbtn").bind( "click", function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1150) {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }
});
```

```css
.border-bottom{
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
    bottom: -11px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
}


.logo{
    float:left;
    }
.logo img{
        width:290px;
    }
.custom-navi{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 55px;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn i {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #009fda;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  padding-top:5px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;    
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color:white;
  outline: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 14px 22px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;

}
@media only screen and (min-width:1300px) and (max-width:1600px) {
.custom-navi{
  
  padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.7%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1150px) and (max-width:1300px) {
.topnav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
.dropdown-content {
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding-top:18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  z-index:999;
  background-color:white;

  
}
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #009fda;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
  color: #002776;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block;

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1150px) {
   
.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
   position: relative;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding-top:18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  z-index:999;
  background-color:white;
  
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in, visibility 300s ease-in;

}
    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
   .logo img{
        padding-left:11px;
    }
  .custom-navi{
     margin:0;
     padding: 0px;
  }  
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative; width:100%; margin-top:15px;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;padding-left:10px;padding-top:0px;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
  }

}

.active{
    color:#002776 !important;
}
  
  

#nav-icon3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

 #nav-icon3 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009fda;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}


.main{background-color:#eee;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section class="custom-navi">
<div class="logo">
      <a href="#">LOGO</a>

 </div>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Statements of work     <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
<!-- Subnavi Elements-->
     
      <a >Contact persons</a>
      <a >Contact persons</a>
      <a >Contact persons</a>
      <a >Contact persons</a>
    </div>
  </div>



<!-- Navigation element mit subnavi-->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">IT 
    </button>
<!-- Subnavi Elements-->
   
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <div id="nav-icon3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div></a>
</div>

</section>

<br><br><br><br>
<div class="main">
  Page Body
</div>
```